# "L" direction javascript animation

Tags: javascript, animation

I want to make my animation to have an "L" direction. After going down,it will move to the right. but when I try to do it, it only moves in a diagonal path.

```
(function () {    
    var speed = 50,
        walkingCat = document.getElementById("catwalk"),
        catWalk = function () {    
            left = walkingCat.offsetLeft,
            moveBy = 10;    
            walkingCat.style.left = left + moveBy + "px";    
        if (left > 850) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    };    
    var timer = setInterval(catWalk, speed);        
    var catWalkDown = function () {            
        var top = walkingCat.offsetTop,
            moveBy = 10;    
            walkingCat.style.top = top + moveBy + "px";    
        if (top > 850) {
            clearInterval(timer2);
        }
    };    
    var timer2 = setInterval(catWalkDown, speed);       
} ());
```

Comment: Your code is doing what you are expecting. Moving down and right at the same time (as the timers fire). If you mean "L" is move left then you want to decrease `left` rather than increase it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way-

**Html**

```
<div id="catwalk" style="position:relative;width:5px;height:5px;background:black"> </div>
```

And in 
**JS**

```
(function () { 
    var speed = 50,
    walkingCat = document.getElementById("catwalk"),
    timer =null,
    catWalk = function () { 
        left = walkingCat.offsetLeft,
        moveBy = 10; 
        walkingCat.style.left = left + moveBy + "px"; 
    if (left > 550) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    } 
}; 
var catWalkDown = function () {

    var top = walkingCat.offsetTop,
        moveBy = 10;

        walkingCat.style.top = top + moveBy + "px";

    if (top > 550) {
        clearInterval(timer2);
        timer = setInterval(catWalk, speed); 
    } 
}; 
var timer2 = setInterval(catWalkDown, speed); }());
```